# Gmapping with Windows OS

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Has anyone tried the slam_gmapping package with Windows OS (particularly Windows 7 64-bit). I am interested to run the Gmapping algorithm in Windows instead of Linux. In my project, I use LabVIEW (in Windows) as the programming language and it turns out that I need to apply the Gmapping algorithm.

Has anyone has any experience in using the slam_gmapping package with other programming language? Any comments and suggestions are much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70315/gmapping-with-windows-os/) by [clonzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5689/clonzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a toolkit for labview:
http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/nl/nid/210716

But you are making it yourself very difficult as a beginner to use ROS on Windows. If you just want to recreate the gmapping algorithm you should read the paper about it and implement it yourself.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clonzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5689/clonzz/) on 2013-08-01**:
Please see my answer above. I think recreating the Gmapping algorithm would take plenty of time considering I need to fully understand the algorithm and carefully rewriting the code. I prefer to use the same code but this may mean that I need to write a wrapper for Gmapping or ROS's slam_gmapping.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have downloaded the toolkit, but haven't try it. If I install the ROS on a Virtual Machine (Ubuntu), can I run gmapping on the ubuntu while on Labview side, I just feed the odometry and laser data and getting the most recent map from ROS? Is there any function from ROS to get the map matrix?

---

Originally posted by [clonzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5689/clonzz/) with karma: 60 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1